# AWS Delete CloudWatch Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

In my bill management board, 0 dollar is charged labeled as "AmazonCloudWatch APN2-TimedStorage-ByteHrs".
Before I close my account, I want to make sure all the resources are closed but I can't find a way to terminate this resource. Does anyone know how to terminate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go the Asia Pacific region Seoul (APN2) and the cloudwatch service to see if anything has been created there (log groups etc). Also worth checking if a cloudtrail trail is set up with global view

If nothing is there, it is worth checking the Cost and Usage Report for Cloudwatch
Billing -> Cost & Usage Reports -> AWS Usage Report -> AmazonCloudWatch to see where/if it thinks you are using resources. it could be that you had a 1 byte file in there at somepoint, that is why it is showing up.

if you find nothing, and no charges associated, then i would feel confident you could close the account down